# passing only date as parameter in stored procedure to get results

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, stored-procedures

I just created following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FindIncomplete_Products]
     @type nvarchar(250),
     @category nvarchar(250),
     @country nvarchar(250),
     @subsidary nvarchar(250),
     @date datetime
AS
Begin  
    select  [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductID],
            [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductTitleEn],
            [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductTitleAr], 
            [dbo].[AB_Product].[Status],
            [dbo].[AB_ProductType].[ProductTypeNameEn],
            [dbo].[AB_ProductType].[ProductTypeNameAr], 
            [dbo].[AB_ProductTypeCategory].[ProductCategoryNameEn],
            [dbo].[AB_ProductTypeCategory].[ProductCategoryNameAr],
            [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[SubsidaryNameEn],
            [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[SubsidaryNameAr],
            [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[Country]
    from 
        [dbo].[AB_Product]
    inner join 
        [dbo].[AB_ProductType] on [dbo].[AB_ProductType].[ProductTypeID] = [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductTypeID]
    inner join 
        [dbo].[AB_ProductTypeCategory] on [dbo].[AB_ProductTypeCategory].[ProductCategoryID] = [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductCategoryID]
    inner join 
        [dbo].[AB_Subsidary] on [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[SubsidaryID] = [dbo].[AB_Product].[Subsidary_ID]
    WHERE 
       (@type IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductTypeID]  LIKE '%' +  @type + '%')
       AND (@category IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[ProductCategoryID] LIKE '%' +  @category + '%')
       AND (@country IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Subsidary].[Country] LIKE '%' +  @country + '%')
       AND (@subsidary IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[Subsidary_ID] LIKE '%' +  @subsidary + '%')
       AND (@date IS NULL OR [dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate] = @date)
End
```

My database field is datetime field which is `[dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate]` when I'm accessing this stored procedure I passed values for data parameter in this format `mm-dd-yyyy` .

since this is looking for exact value for Create Date field which is `AND ([dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate] = @date)` I cannot get all similar results.

for example if I want to search all the products that created date has `2015-08-27` , once I pass that as parameter value I cannot get all the results that created date has `2015-08-27` only I can get results that has created date like this `2015-08-27 00:00:00.000`. I missed results such as create date value has `2015-08-27 13:03:50.647`

Comment: If you have used sql server 2008 or later version then pass @date parameter with `date` datatype rather than `datetime` in stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateDiff` function instead of `=` to compare dates. Example shown below.

```
declare @str nvarchar(25)
set @str = '2015-09-17'
print datediff(d,getdate(),@str)
```

this `DateDiff` will return number of days difference between two dates. So change your last line as follows.

```
(@date IS NULL OR datediff(d,[dbo].[AB_Product].[CreatedDate],@date) = 0)
```

DateDiff works as follows.

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )
```

You can read about DateDiff at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) ....